# reactive 4.2.0 net Subject<T> ReplaySubject<T>

Tags: reactive

I am using ReplaySubject as a pipe when I feed the Observer with OnNext messages and then I subscribe to the message in another part of the code.

I tried ISubject first, by using Subject.Create(observer:, observable:) but this seems to do nothing, or in other words, the Observer is a sink that goes nowhere.  Is there some code that will make the Subject do something pipe-like.  For example, I want to inject onNext messages with a integral countN and I want the observable to broadcast N-many 0.00E0(s) in sequence.

UPDATE:
It seems I need to implement the ISubject interface.  Is there source code for a simple implementation that functions the same as ReplaySubject, with simple, proper memory handling of buffer size and Observer collection and Disposable return object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you use

```
new Subject<Int32>()
```

to get a subject that is a pipe-line.

Someone care to explain what Subject.Create does?

Can you inherit from Subject or ReplaySubject? Should you be able to?